# How to solve "The method values() is undefined for the type List<Map.Entry<String,String>>"

Tags: java, list, arraylist

First of all, I have two string arraylist. Then I combined them together of these two arraylist string.

the two string arraylist looks like this:

`d1 = [a1,a2,a3,a3]`

`d2 = [z1,z2,z3,z3]`

As what I found from people suggestion, I combined both of this string arraylist like this:

```
List<Map.Entry<String, String>> multiall = new ArrayList<>(d1.size());
        if (d1.size() == d2.size()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < d1.size(); ++i) {
                multiall.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, String>(d1.get(i), d2.get(i)));
            }
        }
```

and the result after combining the two string arraylist looks like this:

`[a1=z1, a2=z2,a3=z3,a3=z3]`

and now I removed the duplicate like this:

`multiall = multiall.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());`

and the result of this is like this:

`[a1=z1, a2=z2,a3=z3]`

Now what I want to do is I want to convert it into a string arraylist. I have tried like this:

`ArrayList<String> targetList = new ArrayList<>(multiall.values());`

But I got error saying like this:

`The method values() is undefined for the type List<Map.Entry<String,String>>`

My expected output is like this:

`[a1=z1,a2=z2,a3=z3]` as a string arraylist. is that possible? or my concept is wrong?

please help me. thank you

Comment: Something like this: `multiall.stream().map(kv -> kv.value()).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.values()` work with maps, not lists.

Try:

```
List<String> targetList = multiall.stream()
        .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Also, `List<Map.Entry<String, String>>` doesn't look right. You should use a `Map` instead.

**Update**

Change the stream map to:-

```
.map(entry -> entry.getKey() + "=" + entry.getValue())
```

You can also change your `List<Map.Entry>` to a map and use the overridden `toString()`:-

```
Map<String, String> stringMap = multiall.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

System.out.println(stringMap);
```

Comment: I tried your solution but I got the output only the value of `d2`. do you have any idea why?

Comment: @sharky because you wanted values, didn't you? The elements of `d1` are the "keys". Do you want a list of strings as `["a1=z1", "a2=z2", "a3=z3"]`?

Comment: I am so sorry. I am bit confused. yes, I want a list of string. is that possible to do it? or my concept is wrong? @Kartik

Comment: I am still stuck at the `.map(entry -> entry.getKey() + "=" + entry.getValue())`

Comment: `List<String> targetList = multiall.stream()
                .map(entry -> entry.getKey() + "=" + entry.getValue())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());`